# How to store and query different data

Tags: sql, storage

I need to know what is the best practice for storing the following data:

Lets say I have multiple garages, each garage holds different types of vehicles with totally different attributes (e.g. planes, tanks, ships, bikes). I need to query all the vehicles in one garage, including their attributes.

What would be a good practice to store and query this data with one universal query? Store all vehicles in one table, with every possible attribute? 
Or create multiple tables, each for a specific type of vehicle? Then, how do I query all the different vehicles of one garage, without knowing which type they are?

Is something like this even possible with a single query? Or do I have to create multiple queries to get the data?

I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I think this is more suited to a relational database tutorial than a stack overflow Q and A format. Try [this one](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html) and see how you get on.

Comment: Neither option you suggested is the way to go.  If I can think of a good way to do it, I'll answer the question, unless someone else does first.

Comment: @Dan: Any hint on how you might do it would be a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sure is possible, however it involves some planning when creating your datamodel.

There are, as you already mentioned, different ways to implement sub-type-super-type relations (aka Inheritance).

**1.) All in one Table**

In this case I would model your problem somewhat like this:

```
Garage(GarageId_PK, Name)
Vehicle(VehicleId_PK, LicenceNr, GarageId_FK, SomethingOnlyCarsHave, SoemthingOnlyMortorbikesHave, Type)
```

For the Type you could give IDs and have a separate table where you relate the IDs to Names or simply write the names there (not a very clean solution!).
Btw.: If you want to have multiple inheritance (which I guess you don't need for vehicles) you could also make Type a bitmask.

Personally I don't really like this approach, but it is quite ok to do this. Oracle i.e. suggests this in their study material. Also it's the simpler solution for your one query problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicle v
INNER JOIN Type t ON (v.Type = t.TypeId)
WHERE GarageId = 42
```

**2.) Table for each Subtype**

To me, this feels like the cleaner solution, because you have less NULL values, but you need a bit more work to get everything in one query.

```
Garage(GarageId_PK, Name)
Vehicle(VehicleId_PK, LicenceNr, GarageId_FK)
Car(VechicleId_PK_FK, SomethingOnlyCarsHave)
Motorbike(VechicleId_PK_FK SoemthingOnlyMortorbikesHave)
```

This theoretically allows for multiple inheritance and you should write a trigger allowing only subtype.

SQL in this case:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicles v
     LEFT JOIN Car c ON(v.VehicleId = c.VehicleId)
     LEFT JOIN Motorbike m ON (v.VehicleId = m.VehicleId)
WHERE GarageId = 42
```

Or if you have more types you could put the ugly stuff into a View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE View v_allVehicles AS
(SELECT *
 FROM Vehicles v
      LEFT JOIN Car c ON(v.VehicleId = c.VehicleId)
      LEFT JOIN Motorbike m ON (v.VehicleId = m.VehicleId)

SELECT *
FROM v_allVehicles
```

**EDIT:**

A word on notation: When I put _PK behind a name it referes to the column being a primary key. _FK to a foreign key.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to stick with your solution. However, it requires to update the query every time a new type of vehicle is created. But I guess there is no way to avoid something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

Table garage – garageid, name, other stuff

Table Vehicle – VehicleId, VehicleTypeId, other stuff

Table VehicleType – VehicleTypeId, Type, other stuff

Table Attribute – AttributeId, AttributeName, other stuff

Table VehicleAttribute – VehicleId, AttibuteId, Value, other stuff

Table VehicleGarage – VehicleId, GarageId, DateIn, DateOut, other stuff

Query to get all vehicles and attributes in a garage

```
select v.vehicleId
, vt.type
, a.attributename
, va.value
from VehicleGarage vg join Vehicle v on vg.VehicleId = v. VehicleId
join VehicleType vt on v.VehicleTypeId = vt.VehicleTypeId
join VehicleAttribute va on v.VehicleId = va.VehicleId
join Attribute a on va.AttributeId = a.AttributeId
where garageId = 1
```

For the tables, other stuff would be things like CreatedWhen, CreatedBy and things like that.

Comment: Interesting approach. This way I would not need to do multiple queries or update my query every time a new type is created. I will give this a try, too :) Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a model that looks

```
vehicle_type(vehicle_type_id, description, PK(vehicle_type_id));
 (1, 'bike'; 2, 'plane', ..etc);

vehicle(vehicle_id, vehicle_type_id (FK to  vehicle_type),
 [common attributes], PK(vehicle_id), 
  UNIQUE(vehicle_id,vehicle_type_id ) 
);

bike(vehicle_id,vehicle_type_id , [bike attributes], 
  PK(vehicle_id,vehicle_type_id),
  FK(vehicle_id,vehicle_type_id ) to vehicle, 
  CHECK(vehicle_type_id=1));

plane(vehicle_id,vehicle_type_id , [plane attributes], 
PK (vehicle_id,vehicle_type_id),
  FK(vehicle_id,vehicle_type_id ) to vehicle,
  CHECK(vehicle_type_id=2) 
);

garage(garage_id, name, ..., PK (garage_id));

garage_vehicle(garage_id - FK to garage, 
 vehicle_id - FK to vehicle, PK(garage_id,vehicle_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can store all  the possible garages is a separate table garage.
>   Then store all the vehicles with all possible combination in Vehicles
>   table. In vehicle table add a foreign key column which references

```
create table vehicle(column1,column2...,garageid foreign key references garage)
```

Then to select all the vehicles in a single garage,you can query the vehicle table

```
select * from vehicle where garage='garage_value'
```